# find and replaceNotepad find and replace with regular expression

Tags: html, regex

I have a list like this

```
<option value="01 Asad Gate Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="02 Graphics Building Br, Motijheel</option>
<option value="03 Mirpur Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="04 Uttara Branch, Dhaka</option>
```

want to make it like this in Notepad++ with regular expression find and replace.

```
<option value="01"> Asad Gate Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="02"> Graphics Building Br, Motijheel</option>
<option value="03"> Mirpur Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="04"> Uttara Branch, Dhaka</option>
```

want to replace the space after number with ">

Comment: Would you like to change the space with event or just "onload"?

Answer (score 1):

use as pattern:

```
(<option value="[0-9]*)
```

and replace with:

```
\1">
```

Answer (score 0):

to late :/
or try one of those patterns
pattern: `(="\d+)` or `(value="\d+)` or `(<option value="\d*)`   
replace: `\1">`

\d+ - one or more digit
\d* - 0 or more digits

this pattern `(="\d+)\s+` replaced by `\1">` don't crash your line already fixed

for example:

```
<option value="01 Asad Gate Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="02"> Graphics Building Br, Motijheel</option>
<option value="03 Mirpur Branch, Dhaka</option>
<option value="04 Uttara Branch, Dhaka</option>
```

or you can multi edit line
go with cursor to position "space" after digits,
then press SHIFT + ALT and go down cursor (few times) and then add by typing "> by yourself